# How to show names of variables (stored in a list) in regression output in R?

Tags: r

I'm new to R , sorry if this isn't explained very clearly.

I need to examine the coefficients from many regression models. I want to look at every possible combination of my main predictors and my potential covariates. Creating a custom function, and then a nested for loop, I'm able to get the output I want...perfect! The only problem is that the names of the variables do not appear in the output, making it extremely difficult to read.

All variables are saved in 2 lists, and the lists have been named using `names()`. In previous calculations, the names have automatically appeared in the results, but not here. Below is a simplfied example.

Variables of interest are collected in a list, and then named like so.

```
 
predictors <- list(df$pred1,
                   df$pred2,
                   df$pred3,
                   )

names(predictors) <- c("Hrs/day reading",
                       "Hrs/day TV",
                       "Hrs/day Computer"
                       )
```

Then I've done the exact same for my covariates, leaving me with another named list called "Covariates"

To get the coefficient tables for every combo

```
covariate_models_total <- function(pred,
                                   cov){
  model <- lm(outcome ~ pred + cov, data = df)
  coefs <- summary(model)$coef
  return(coefs)
}


for (p in predictors) {
  for (c in covariates){
    results <- covariate_models_total(p,c)
    print(results)
  }
}
```

The results are tables that look like this

```
                 Estimate Std. Error     t value   Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept) 54.6909179143 31.8207606  1.71871812 0.09173122
pred        -5.8995651667  3.5564502 -1.65883532 0.10328739
cov         -6.2504111266  5.1593890 -1.21146344 0.23130134
```

Which is great, but with 100+ of them, I need labels to know what I'm looking at.

I've tried variations of `print(p)` or `print(name(p))`. I've tried adjusting both the function and the loop. Ideally, `pred` and `cov` would be replaced with the variable names directly in the table, but I'd be happy to see them directly above (like how they appear in previous outputs).

I feel like it should be so simple, can anybody point me in the right direction? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `print`ing, store it in a `list`

```
out <- list()
for (p in predictors) {
  for (c in covariates){
    results <- covariate_models_total(p,c)
    results <- list(results)
    names(results) <- paste0(p, "_", c)
    out <- c(out, results)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've tried what you've posted, and I get the error 
`Error in names(object) <- nm : 
  'names' attribute [56] must be the same length as the vector [1]`

Also I'm not sure what you mean by the last part.

Comment: Can you try the update.  From your code, I assume that `results` from `covariate_models_total` is a list, which i wrapped in a `list` and then named it.

Comment: Gave that a try and got the same error as above. `results` are just coefficients from the models. I'm not sure if they're stored in a list by default. Since I only need the coefficients (SE, t and p values aren't used in this step of my analysis), is it worth trying get the output of my function to be a list of only coefficients, and then maybe your code will work?

Comment: @jane07907 in your function, you are extracting it as `return(coefs)`.  So, when iwrap the output in a `list`, it shouldn't have any error though